# Why python string cut returns 11 symbols when 12 is requested?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

I use python 2.7 on OSX 10.9 and would like to cut unicode string (`05. Чайка.mp3`) by 12 symbols, so I use `mp3file[:12]` to cut it by 12 symbols. But in result I get the string like `05. Чайка.m`, which is 11 symbols only. But `len(mp3file[:12])` returns 12. Looks like the problem is with Russian symbol `й`.

What could be wrong here?

The main problem with this - I can not normally display strings with `{:<12}'.format(mp3file[:12])`.

Comment: What is the original string?

Comment: Is the original string prefixed with a magic whitespace codepoint like a BOM?

Comment: @sshashank124, I've updated the question with the exact string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it shows `u'05. \u0427\u0430\u0438\u0306\u043a\u0430.m'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have unicode text with a combining character:

```
u'05. \u0427\u0430\u0438\u0306\u043a\u0430.m'
```

The [U+0306](http://codepoints.net/U+0306) is a COMBINING BREVE codepoint, `̆`, it combines with the preceding [`и` CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER I](http://codepoints.net/U+0438) to form:

```
>>> print u'\u0438'
и
>>> print u'\u0438\u0306'
й
```

You can [normalize that to the combined form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode/16467505#16467505), [U+0439 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER SHORT I](http://codepoints.net/U+0439) instead:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFC', u'\u0438\u0306')
u'\u0439'
```

This uses the [`unicodedata.normalize()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) to produce a composed normal form.

Comment: Thanks, got it. But how should I display it properly with `{:<12}.format` then?

Comment: @LA_: you can use the normalized form; I added an example.

Comment: We could do with a canonical answer that addresses issues like this...  great answer that'd I more than +1 if I could though :)

Comment: [`.normalize()` may fail to combine Unicode codepoints that belong to the same graphem cluster](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23323520/4279)

Answer (score 3):

A user-perceived character ([grapheme cluster](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/)) such as `й` may be constructed using several [Unicode codepoints](http://codepoints.net/), each Unicode codepoints in turn may be encoded using several bytes depending on a character encoding.

Therefore number of characters that you see may be less the corresponding sizes of Unicode or byte strings that encode them and you can also truncate inside a Unicode character if you slice a bytestring or inside a user-perceived character if you slice a Unicode string even if it is in NFC [Unicode normalization form](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/). Obviously, [it is not desirable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12746458/4279).

To properly [count characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9730835/4279), you could use `\X` [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) that matches [eXtended grapheme cluster (a language independent "visual character")](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/):

```
import regex as re # $ pip install regex

characters = re.findall(u'\\X', u'05. \u0427\u0430\u0438\u0306\u043a\u0430.m')
print(characters)
# -> [u'0', u'5', u'.', u' ', u'\u0427', u'\u0430', 
#     u'\u0438\u0306', u'\u043a', u'\u0430', u'.', u'm']
```

Notice, that even without normalization: `u'\u0438\u0306'` is a separate character `'й'`.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFC', u'\u0646\u200D ') # 3 Unicode codepoints
u'\u0646\u200d ' # still 3 codepoints, NFC hasn't combined them
>>> import regex as re
>>> re.findall(u'\\X', u'\u0646\u200D ') # same 3 codepoints
[u'\u0646\u200d', u' '] # 2 grapheme clusters
```

See also, [In Python, how do I most efficiently chunk a UTF-8 string for REST delivery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22718831/4279)

Comment: Detecting graphemes will not help fitting in a fixed character width when formatting a string, though. Isn't Unicode fun? I can't wait till the OP discovers wide Asian characters! :-P

Comment: At the very least graphemes tell you how many characters you will see on the screen. :) Width may be context dependent even for ASCII.

Comment: How does `\X` handle zero-width spaces or Bidi marks (right-to-left, left-to-right), etc. btw? You demoed with a zero-width joiner here. Just curious; I should probably just install `regex` again and test this myself..

Comment: [the first link](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/) in the answer describes all the gory details

Comment: I see there are *tailored* grapheme clusters (locale specific, such as `ch` in Slovak, or the `ij` in my Dutch name), but presumably `regex` doesn't support those. No mention in the documentation, at least.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: \X doesn't match tailored graphemes.